# What was the original purpose and origin of complimentary closes?

Tags: politeness, letter-writing

Emails and letters commonly end with a closing phrase such as

> Yours faithfully,
>   Jonny McJoe

...but I never understood the reason why such a thing would come up in the first place.

Maybe it's because letters were (a long time ago) longer and better written, possibly a glorified form of communication that expressed more than just the message they contained, and closing them in a way that showed good taste, politeness, etc was part of that glorification?

In modern usage they sound very weird to me, like

> Hello.
>
> I've sent the PDF with the report, be sure to backup before the maintenance this time!
>
> Yours sincerely,
>   Gregor McGreg

So, why it was invented, or under what sort of influence it became the norm?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! This question is not a good fit because it's open ended. We limit ourselves to language and usage questions that we can give a definite "right" answer to.

Comment: For purely communication purposes, it tells the reader that the mail transmission is complete.

Comment: @MetaEd Is it? I'll try to edit, please tell me if it still is.

Comment: @Mitch that sound so mechanic and pragmatic. Was this a concern (that the letter was at its end) in old times?

Comment: I doubt an edit will help. This is, fundamentally, *not an English language question*. Letters in many languages and cultures have these features.

Comment: @Camilo: Most likely not. But in hand written letters, if you know there is some kind of sign-off at the end (flowery or not), then if there isn't one, then you may be able to realize that the last page of the letter is missing. Not necessarily by design, but a convenient side-effect.

Comment: @MetaEd I see. As I cannot seem to be able to vote to close, however, I don't know what to do.

Comment: @CamiloMartin Well, you ***could*** accept an answer. That might remove the motivation for others to add their own and draw it out.  Or not.  I don’t know.

Comment: @tchrist fair enough, your answer is good. Maybe it can be left at that.

Comment: Closed; complimentary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can’t imagine writing a proper letter out in longhand without a proper valediction at the end.   Would you leave a friend’s home without saying good-bye?

It’d be like having a converstation with someone, or even delivering a lecture to a group, and then without any warning or adieu rudely turning your back on them  and strutting off without even so much as a ‘Thank you’ or a ‘See ya’ or an ‘Hasta pronto, tonto.’

It seems rude and precipitous, even capricious.  Definitely unfriendly.

Comment: "hasta pronto, tonto"? Never heard of that in spanish, but it means "see you later, fool". I also agree with not finishing a letter without some sort of goodbye, but I'm asking more about the formal kind, like the ready-made templates I mentioned. Usually (in an email, or a note, only once in my life I've posted a phyisical letter) I end by writing something personal, such as "Looking forward to see you soon!". If it is an email I happen to use "cheers" or "best regards", however.

Comment: @CamiloMartin I know what the phrase means; I’m a fluent Spanish speaker. I’m making a joke about the old *Lone Ranger* series, where the Ranger’s sidekick was named Tonto. It’s rhyme-y and silly in English, if they don’t clue.  With email, it depends on the length whether I have a comma-terminated *“Something something,”* line before my name at the end, but I always always have my name at the end. It lets the other person know that you actually meant to end the letter, that it didn’t just escape unfinished.  Which, in fact, has also been known to occur to me from time to time. Unfortunately.

Comment: +1 for (among other things) a new good word for me - valediction :)

Comment: @CamiloMartin To clarify, *Hasta pronto, Tonto* is American slang, kinda like *See ya later, Alligator*. It would be rude in Spanish. Also, it has to be pronounced *Hasta pranto, tanto* which makes no sense in Spanish (*pranto* is Portuguese for Spanish *llanto*, though). The formula “Hasta ______” is reasonably common slang in (non-bilingual) American English. Think of Schwarzenegger (my what a rude name! :) when he famously said ‘Hasta la vista, baby.’ You even hear folks say ‘Hasta la byebye’, which of course makes no sense, but still.

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan As saludictorians have their salutations, so too do valedictorians have their valedictions. Most everybody else just says hello and goodbye. :)

Comment: @tchrist I can't say I didn't knew about the portuguese meaning of *pranto*, but congratulations for you to know even such a language. I see, so "Hasta..." has also been added to english (like "amigo") and became a meme.

Comment: @CamiloMartin Just so. The OED2 gives the first *hasta la vista* citation in English as 1935, but I bet that gets antedated for its 3rd Edition update. Last year the OED added *gordita* 1835, *abuelo* 1879, *abuela* 1836, *abuelito* 1937, & *salsa verde* 1957 as attested English words — ***¿Quién lo sabía?*** ☺ And from Portuguese, *turbinado* (sugar) 1909. Lots of French like *giclée* 1995, and Latin, including the famous *ab urbe condita* (A.U.C.), whose first attested English citation is 1602. Gee, it sure takes them long enough, eh? And *framboid* 1962 for raspberry-shaped, but of course.

Comment: @CamiloMartin I’m American, but were I a monoglot my world would be much smaller and less interesting, and I would have many fewer friends, some of whom I hold quite dear. And I would lose so much poetry: *Verde verde te quiero verde* of Lorca, *De los sos oios tan fuertemientre llorando* del Mio Çid, that *selva oscura ché la diritta via era smarrita* of Dante, *As armas e os barões assinalados* of Camões, *Arma  virumque cano* of Virgil, *Mais où sont les neiges d’antan?* of Villon, *des mots qui font vivre… certains noms de fleurs…et de fruits* of Eluard. Almost not a life worth living, eh?

Comment: @tchrist What can I say, you're awesome. +1 for every of your comments here.

Comment: On a more on-the-topic-of-the-off-topic note, *Turbinado* currently is a Brazilian slang along the lines of "pimped up", drawing the more proper usage of "car engines that have a turbine". Never tought it could have been a sugar.

Answer (score 1):

It's a marker. You would want to have a symbolic end-of-message marker before your signature. Your reader would not appreciate something that seems to abruptly lead to your signature, without so much as a "so that's just about it, then".

It is not special to the English language; it exists in communications in practically all languages.

Comment: I wonder when it was first invented. Japan traditionally was a very isolated country, yet they seem to have a quite mechanical approach to addressing each other, so maybe the standardization of messages is a natural step after the creation of a language.

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple. Whenever you meet people, it is common to greet them as a way of starting some  form of communicative activity. As the activity comes to an end, you indicate this by using appropriate language.

In the English language, "Hi" and "Bye" are among the simplest ways of observing this convention. At the other end of the spectrum, you may have an audience with Her Majesty, The Queen. In which case, the ritual will become much more embellished.

By the same token, other forms of communication also observe an appropriate form of this convention. For example, "Dear Sir or Madam:" and "Faithfully yours,".

Of course, rituals do change over time. However, I imagine that the convention of "Hello" and "Goodbye" (opening and closing) is pretty basic and will be with us for a long time to come.

Comment: Let's leave complicated greeting boilerplate to [the Borg](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WZEJ4OJTgg8). Minimalism is so important in a society whose biggest communication problem is noise, IMHO.